# MS Office spell check is not working with non-English languages from managed api

Tags: c#, ms-office

I'm trying to get spell checking working using MS Office in different languages using the c# api.  I have all the relevant language packs installed.  For instance, if I put in the German misspelled word "buxs" I get English suggestions: bus, buss, buds ,boxes, bugs ,bums ,buys ,box's ,buns ,burs.  But I'm expecting suggestions like this: Bus, büxt, bis, büxe, Bugs, Buhs.

My code is below...   What am I doing wrong?

```
wordApp = new Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
WdLanguageID language = WdLanguageID.wdGerman;

wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordDocument.Content.LanguageID = language;

// This is mis-spelled. 
string misSpelledWord = "buxs";

// this returns english suggestions...
SpellingSuggestions theSuggestions = wordApp.GetSpellingSuggestions( misSpelledWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref suggestionMode, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: There's some monkeying going on with a custom dictionary in the [MSDN article for LanguageID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839161%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  Hard to guess why but it sure sounds related.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests with both `GetSpellingSuggestions` in the `Word Application` and in a `Range` and the behaviour you describe seems to be the normal one. The language on my computer is Spanish and when I use your code (with `WdLanguageID.wdSpanish` and `"buxs"`), I get the suggestions you refer (same ones when I moved to English). On the other hand, when I change to German I don't get anything. Also I have tested "clearly suggestable" words in Spanish ("kasa" or "part") and the results have been fine.

My conclusion is that if the word can be found in the target dictionary, it delivers these results; otherwise, it looks in the English dictionary. Apparently, "buxs" is not included in the German dictionary.